# Is the phrase "in place" a good synonym for "appropriate"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Would it be appropriate to use "in place" as a synonym for the word "appropriate?"

In this sentence, for example:

> "I thought it would be in place for us to erect a statue for the late poet."

If not, is there a similar phrase that would be more apt?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot for the correction. Erect, not enact. Are there any idioms that could substitute **"appropriate"** in that context?

Comment: Why not use "appropriate"? Also: does it need to be a prepositional phrase?

Comment: Why do you need an idiom or a phrase? There are a lot of single-word synonyms for appropriate (fitting, meet, suitable, just, right, proper, pertinent, congruous...).

Comment: Did you mean to be ironic when you ended your post with the word "apt"? Because that is a common synonym for "appropriate".

Comment: The words *in place…erect* are odd together. See the meaning of *in place* under **Phrases** and it can generally mean *in order* as in *ready.* https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20place

Comment: It sounds like you’re trying to roll your own antonym for *out of place*. Best not attempt that with idioms.

Comment: May I draw your attention to our sister site, SE English Language Learners, which I think is more appropriate for questions of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had to use an idiom, you could use *in order* instead of *in place*, as in:

> I thought a statue for the late poet would be in order.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/order) defines "in order" as:

> : APPROPRIATE, DESIRABLE
> an apology is in order

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the phrase I was looking for.

Comment: @JahtominiOgunderu Glad you like it.